# Separate column values and create new columns with these values in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe, `df`, where I would like to separate column values and create new columns with these values.

Data:

```
ID  Date      STAT
aa  Q1 2022   hi
aa  Q1 2022   hi
aa  Q1 2022   hi
```

Desired:

```
ID  Date      STAT  QTR YEAR
aa  Q1 2022   hi    Q1  2022
aa  Q1 2022   hi    Q1  2022
aa  Q1 2022   hi    Q1  2022
```

I've tried using `.str.split` to separate values within the columns:

```
df['Date'].str.split(' ', expand=True)
```

However, I'm unsure about how to create the new columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
df[['QTR', 'YEAR']] = df['Date'].str.split(' ', expand=True)
```

Output:

```py
   ID     Date STAT QTR  YEAR
0  aa  Q1 2022   hi  Q1  2022
1  aa  Q1 2022   hi  Q1  2022
2  aa  Q1 2022   hi  Q1  2022
```

Comment: thank you - I tried on my full dataset and getting a value error - ValueError: Columns must be same length as key - will debug

Comment: Hmm, that's confusing. Your code in the question splits by `,`, the dataframe uses ` ` (space), and you're now saying it should split by `_` (underscore). Which one should it be?

Comment: Correction I believe the ending should be : df.Date.str.split(" ",expand=True,)

Comment: That's working? But it's not different from my code above, except that it uses `df.Date` instead of `df['Date']` (which are both identical, by the way).

Comment: Will try it now